# How to convert to double with 2 precision - string after dot?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, double, precision

I want to convert this string: `0.55000000000000004` to this double: `0.55`.
How to do that?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Is a string or a double?
If it is a string:

```
double d = double.Parse(s,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
string s=string.Format("{0:0.00}",d);
```

if it is already a double just format using the second line.

Comment: The CultureInfo.InvariantCulture format provider is the one to use if your decimal separator is always ".", what exactly you need to know ?

Comment: And if you want to do it without trailing zeroes you can use [{0:#,0.######}](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20146494/492336)

Answer (score 52):

you can use this code to reduce precision part:

```
double m = Math.Round(0.55000000000000004,2);
```

Result would be : 0.55

Answer (score 12):

There *is no* double 0.55 - the number cannot be accurately represented as a binary fraction. Which is probably the reason why you got that long string in the first place. You should probably be using the `decimal` type instead of `double`.

Read [The Floating-Point Guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/) to understand why.

Comment: @PokemonCraft: No. What you need is to understand why what you want is impossible and does not make sense.