# Storing a double with 2 digit precision

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

How do I convert a double to have precision of 2 places?

For ex:

```
    double x = 1.00d;           
    Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(x,2,MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
//Should output 1.00 for me, but it outputs just 1.
```

What I'm looking for is to store 1.00 in a double variable which when printed to console prints 1.00.

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: Have you seen this topic? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997085/c-sharp-convert-to-double-with-2-precision-string-after-dot

Answer (score 21, accepted):

"x" stores the number - it doesn't pay attention to the precision.

To output the number *as a string* with a specific amount of precision, use a [format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx), ie:

```
Console.WriteLine(x.ToString("F2"));
```

Answer (score 5):

`double` is an IEEE-754 double-precision floating point number.  It always has exactly 53 bits of precision.  It does not have a precision that can be exactly represented in "decimal places" -- as the phrase implies, "decimal places" only measures precision relative to the base-10 number system.

If what you want is simply to change the precision the value is *displayed* with, then you can use one of the `ToString()` overloads to do that, as other answers here point out.

Remember too that `double` is an approximation of a *continuous* real value; that is, a value where there is no implied discrete quantization (although the values are in fact quantized to 53 bits).  If what you are trying to represent is a *discrete* value, where there is an implicit quantization (for example, if you are working with currency values, where there is a significant difference between 0.1 and 0.099999999999999) then you should probably be using a data type that is based on integer semantics -- either a fixed-point representation using a scaled integer or something like the .NET `decimal` type.

Comment: "It does not ever have a precision that can be exactly represented by any finite number of decimal places." Not so! Some examples: 0.5, 0.25, 0.75, etc.; in other words, fractions whose denominator is a power of two.  (Also, any integer that's representable by the double type can be represented exactly.)

Comment: @phoog: Yeah, I had actually edited that sentence before you posted your comment.  Indeed a double can hold a value that has an exact precision in decimal.  The point I was trying to make, however, was that "decimal places" is not always a valid measurement of precision.  If you are measuring a binary precision in "decimal places" you are not going to have an exact result.  (For example, `double` has a precision of approximately 15.9 decimal places.)  If you have a better idea of how to express that, I'd be happy to adjust my answer.

Comment: Hmm, good point.  Maybe something like "there's no exact conversion between the number of places of position in base 2 and base 10."  But I'm not entirely satisfied with that either.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a question of *storing*, it is a question of *formatting*.

This code produces `1.00`:

```
double x = 1.00d;
Console.WriteLine("{0:0.00}", Math.Round(x, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero));
```

Comment: Why call Math.Round when the `0.00` format specifier will round the value?

Comment: @phoog I kept `Math.Round` there only to keep the answer as close to the OP's code as possible; other than that, it is entirely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

The `decimal` data type has a concept of variable precision.  The double data type does not.  Its precision is always 53 bits.

The default string representation of a double rounds it slightly to minimize odd-looking values like `0.999999999999`, and then drops any trailing zeros.  As other answers note, you can change that behavior by using one of the type's `ToString` overloads.