# How to read the trailing zero from Excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am reading data from an Excel sheet as test data,

- Two numbers I need to read are 17.50 and 52.50
- I have configured under Format Cells -> Custom to have 17.50 and 52.50 displayed instead of 17.5 and 52.5

But when I read the two cells, I got 17.5 and 52.5 respectively.

Anyone has a solution?

Comment: The values are technically correct.  If you want to maintain the 2 decimal precision when performing calculations you would have to indicate that at the time.  You can also manipulate them at the time of display to include a trailing zero.  Your variables in C# only care about the value, they care nothing for formatting, you have to address that at the time of using the values.  See also:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403491/storing-a-double-with-2-digit-precision

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all your needing to do is display 17.5, as 17.50 and are always expecting 2 decimal places, you can do the following:

```
excelValue.ToString("#.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: what if i need 17.50 on one and 18.516 on another?