# Format double - thousands separator with decimal but no trailing zeros

Tags: c#, string, format

I am looking for a format to use with *string.Format* that would print the following

```
double d = 123456.123456D;
double d2 = 123456D;
```

like

```
123,456.123456
123,456
```

{0:N6} results in

```
123,456.123456
123,456.000000
```

{0:0.######} results in

```
123456.123456
123456
```

{0:#.0} results in

```
123,456
123,456
```

I cannot workout a format that will get me to what I need. Will I need to define my own format provider ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're close.  Use this format:

```
{0:#,0.######}
```

Comment: +1 I thought it was along those lines, my answer was just missing the `######` part.

Comment: @CristianoSousa Use `#,0.######` instead.  I have updated my answer since that's a better format.

Comment: @DStanley Works perfectly!

Comment: note: when using `ToString()`, then the above should be `#,0.#####` (without the braces or the first zero+colon)