# "Double" data type formatting

Tags: c#, formatting, double, number-formatting

So I'm a beginner C# programmer and cannot seem to figure out how to format a double to show a ".00" at the end of a WHOLE NUMBER. Keep in mind, I do not simply want the program to display the ".00" but want the variable to actually take that value. I cannot get this to occur even if I divide the value by "1.00". Perhaps someone would be able to show me how to cast a variable to have 2 decimal places as I would need to cast some variables and perform arithmetic with them in order to save an answer to a double variable.
I would truly appreciate any help on this matter. 
Thank you very much

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997085/c-sharp-convert-to-double-with-2-precision-string-after-dot

Comment: Show your code. And bear in mind floating-point data types cannot represent decimal values precisely.

Comment: No matter how you slice it, a double will represent all the precision it can. It might be "2.0000000000000" but it will *never* be "2.00"