# convert to double cutting off zeroes

Tags: c#

I have an array that contains product names and prices such as thingy25.00 but when I run this line of code below I get 25 and all zeroes are gone.  I need to keep two decimal point after the period so basically 25.00.

```
    price[i] = Convert.ToDouble(product[i].Substring(7, 4));
```

Comment: 25 is numerically identical to 25.00, the only difference is when you print it out.

Comment: You're confusing presentation (appearance) with content (value). The double does indeed contain 25.00; your **presentation** may not show them. How are you presenting the number?

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4997085/c-sharp-convert-to-double-with-2-precision-string-after-dot) some of the answers there might be helpful.

Comment: If you need it to be a numeric value, then actually you're all set. You've got the value (25), you just need to format it when displaying: `price[i].ToString("C2")`.

Comment: Please read c# language specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will once you format the output like this:

```
var s = price[i].ToString("#,##0.00");
```

Comment: The code in the question adds the double to an array. If `price` is an array of doubles (as the code indicates it is), you can't add to it using `ToString()`.

Comment: I'm not adding to it.  I'm showing how to format the output.

Comment: @TMcKeown Your format string is wrong. You need `"#,##0.00"` to force the zeroes after the decimal point.

Comment: going off the top of my head here.

Comment: The question says *Convert to double cutting off zeroes*. Where does it ask anything about formatting a string?